# VS Code Extension. Code highlighting for comparison does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparison, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

I'm writing an extension in Visual Studio Code that should generate assembler code from the current open code "C" or "C++". And after hovering over a line of code in "C" or "C++", the section of code generated from this line should be highlighted. Kind of like a comparison.

**extensions.js**

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const vscode = require("vscode");
const path = require('path');

function activate(context) {
  let decorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5)'
  });

  let mapping = {};

  // Register the hover provider
  vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(['c', 'cpp'], {
    provideHover(document, position) {
      let lineNum = position.line;
      let assemblerEditor = vscode.window.visibleTextEditors.find(e => e.document.languageId === 'assembler');
      if (assemblerEditor) {
        let assemblerLineNum = mapping[lineNum];
        if (assemblerLineNum !== undefined) {
          assemblerEditor.setDecorations(decorationType, [
            new vscode.Range(assemblerLineNum, 0, assemblerLineNum, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
          ]);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Register the command that generates the assembly code and opens it
  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "extension.showAssembly",
    function () {
      let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
      if (!editor) {
        return;
      }

      // Choice compiler
      let config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
      let compiler = config.get("cvass.compiler.choice");
      let currentFilePath = editor.document.uri.fsPath;
      let dirPath = path.dirname(currentFilePath);
      let oFile = path.join(dirPath, 'output.s');
      let iFile = currentFilePath;

      exec(`${compiler} -S -o "${oFile}" "${iFile}"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          vscode.window.showErrorMessage(error);
          return;
        }

        // populate the mapping object
        let output = stdout + stderr;
        let lines = output.split('\n');
        lines.forEach((line, index) => {
          if (line.startsWith(currentFilePath)) {
            let cLineNum = parseInt(line.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
            mapping[cLineNum] = index;
          }
        });

        vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(oFile).then(doc => {
          vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, vscode.ViewColumn.Beside, true);
        });
      });
    });

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

exports.activate = activate;

function deactivate() { }

module.exports = {
  activate,
  deactivate
};
```

In the code above, my attempt at implementation.

For generation I use "g++" and "clang++"

Expected: that the generated source code file will open in a new tab to the right of the "C", "C++" source code. And when you hover over a line of code in "C", "C++" in the assembler code, the section of code created from this line will be highlighted.

The very generation of the assembler and opening it on the right in a new tab is ready.

I really hope for your help, it is not possible to write this functionality at all.

Comment: Isn't your question actually about JavaScript and not about C or C++?

Comment: @Lundin I pointed out because I think it's related.

Comment: The language id for c++ is `cpp`.  Use that in your HoverProvider.

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much for pointing out my mistake, I've corrected it. However, this did not fix my issue.